# Prove without using a calculator $(\ln 6)^{(\ln 5)^{(\ln 4)^{(\ln 3)^{(\ln 2)}}}}<\pi$

Tags: logarithms, pi

Prove without using a calculator
$$(\ln 6)^{(\ln 5)^{(\ln 4)^{(\ln 3)^{(\ln 2)}}}}<\pi$$
I want to know if there is an easy way to prove this inequality without using a calculator.

Comment: To what base are you taking your logarithms?

Comment: the base is $e$ or I mean $\log x=\ln x$

Comment: May I ask where this problem is from ... interestingly ([with a calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%286%29^%28log%285%29^log%284%29^log%283%29^log%282%29%29+-+pi)) the difference is quite small.

Comment: it looks like a chance rather than having a reason. It it not correct for when you extend it to number 7.

Comment: whats the motivation for doing such a question?

Comment: @Rememberme I would suspect a test/research question of some sort.

Comment: Since a calculator anyway uses calculations that could be performed without a calculator the requirement that it be done without a calculator not that restricting.

Comment: This is approx. $(44)$ at [MathWorld Pi Approximations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiApproximations.html).

Comment: Oh, boy... [Here we go again](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19188)... :-$)$

Comment: OP's silence, failing to address @Rememberme's query, does not help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to prove it, yet. However, I can help motivate a reason to solve it.

As to your question,

"I want to know if there is an easy way to prove this inequality without using a calculator?"

The answer is no. There is no easy/quick proof of this that will make it's way into an answer. However, I have made some observations.

We have a recursion relation of the following,

$$L(x+1)=\ln(x+1)^{L(x)}$$

$$L^{(0)}(\ln(x))=\ln(x) \quad L^{(1)}(\ln(x))=\ln(x+1)^{\ln(x)}$$

$$\ln(23)=3.13549...$$
$$L^{(1)}(\ln(6))={\ln(7)}^{\ln(6)}=3.29623...$$
$$L^{(2)}(\ln(4))={\ln(6)}^{{\ln(5)}^{\ln(4)}}=\color{green}{3.08961...}$$
$$L^{(3)}(\ln(3))={\ln(6)}^{{\ln(5)}^{{\ln(4)}^{\ln(3)}}}=\color{blue}{3.16664...}$$
$$L^{(4)}(\ln(2))={\ln(6)}^{{\ln(5)}^{{\ln(4)}^{{\ln(3)}^{\ln(2)}}}}=\color{red}{3.14157...}$$
$$L^{(5)}(\ln(1))={\ln(6)}^{{\ln(5)}^{{\ln(4)}^{{\ln(3)}^{\ln(2)^{\ln(1)}}}}}=\color{blue}{3.16664...}$$
$$L^{(6)}(\ln(0))={\ln(6)}^{{\ln(5)}^{{\ln(4)}^{{\ln(3)}^{\ln(2)^{\ln(1)^{\ln(0)}}}}}}=\color{green}{3.08961...}$$

I find that interesting and motivating.

Now, some of you might be intrigued by colorful use of $\ln(0)$ above. I actually found that using a limit, we observe the behavior of $L^{(6)}(\ln(x))$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: $\ln(0)$? Something I'm missing? ;-)